# Change code to read different JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code which reads the JSON data:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
    var output = '';

    $.each(data, function(index, value){
    output += '<li>' + value.title + '</li>';

    });
    $('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');
    });
```

The code above can read JSON in this format:

```
[
    {"title":"mytitle1"},
    {"title":"mytitle2"},
    {"title":"mytitle3"}

]
```

I now need to get it to read this JSON format:

```
{"cats":

[

{"title":"mytitle1"},
{"title":"mytitle2"},
{"title":"mytitle3"}

]

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You need to reference the `cats` element in your `each` function.

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
  var output = '';

  $.each(data.cats, function(index, value){
    output += '<li>' + value.title + '</li>';

  });
  $('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your callback to use the "cats" property of the returned data.

Change the line with $.each to something like this:

```
$.each(data.cats, function(index, value){
```

Notice that it is iterating over data.cats, instead of just data.